# play Youtube audio with python Discord bot

Tags: python, audio, youtube, bots, discord

Hey i wanted to know if its possible to play youtube audio without doing anything to special. this is my code:

```
if message.content.upper().startswith('!PLAY'):
    args = message.content.split(" ")
    url = args[1]
    author = message.author
    voice_channel = author.voice_channel
    vc = await Client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)

    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.Start()
```

I thought this was enough but i guess not does anyone have some tips on how to do this if its possible?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should watch some tutorial instead of asking here? Also I'd recommend to do this instead

```py
@client.command()
async def yt(ctx, url):

    author = ctx.message.author
    voice_channel = author.voice_channel
    vc = await client.join_voice_channel(voice_channel)

    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.start()
```

This should work althought I'm not completely sure :)